# Getting more of yearly review than standard

Tags: salary, raise, performance-reviews

My current company does yearly contract reviews. I am about to complete one year with my present company and I know that two work colleagues that (same department but different teams with nearly the same salary as me) had a raise of around 5% salary by their annual review. (4.7% and 5.9%)

They said their bosses just told them how much the raise was going to be and asked them if they agreed. They nodded and the raise was that. There was also a conversation about what they managed to achieve during the year, what they liked most, what they missed and what they were unhappy about.

I am thinking that these values might be something standard here and that I will be "entitled" a similar raise when the time comes.

I would be happy with a raise as well and my expectations are now that I will get  a similar raise (I'd be very disappointed if it wasn't).

Anyway, even though that would make me happy, I would like to have some kind of negotiation if they mention a similar value, so that the raise could be some more than that. **I am very pleased here and have no plans of leaving** but I would like to have a better bonus.

**EDIT**

The question is, how to say "the raise you are offering is good, but I would like some more (maybe double it)"

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @KateGregory, edited the question

Comment: So when he says "Is X% enough?", you say "No, and here's why I think I deserve more."

Comment: Why don't you just say  "Thanks. The raise you are offering is good, but I would like some more." ? There's no magic words here.

Comment: @DavidK, it is not that simple, is it?

Comment: @WorkerDrone, I am not looking for magic words, but saying just "I would like some more" doesn't seem like a good tactic. We would all "like some more"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is bad practice to compare yourself to other colleagues in terms of salary as there are far too many factors involved and this far too often leads to feelings of inadequacy and entitlement in the workplace.

Do not use other people as examples in this meeting saying you deserve to make more than them (mentioning it at all can make it look like this, even if this is not the intention) as this only looks petty and unprofessional, their salary increase should be irrelevant to your capabilities and worth.

However, asking for an increase in salary is always a good idea if you feel you deserve that little bit extra, go to the appraisal with arguments as to why you deserve what you think you deserve and what you bring to the company as well as any living cost increases and make this clear to management and if the money is there and they agree with you, they will give you that raise. Always remember that actual productivity and worth are only one of the variables that go into salary increases and be humble yet convincing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I never considered mentioning other colleagues and their raises. I just mentioned them because they are on similar functions and have a similar salary. It's just natural for me to assume that it can be different with me, of course, but not **completely different** than it was with them

Comment: Of course, I just provide that warning to everyone as the practice of basing your salary entitlement off what you believe others don't do rather than what you do is shockingly common and is one of the worst ways to get a salary increase from any competent manager.

Comment: I agree. I don't care if they get a 1000% raise as long as my raise is what I think it should be. If I am happy with my salary, I am happy with my salary. If others earn double or triple, I don't care

Comment: Why do you think you deserve a 10% raise? 2-3% is most common annual cost of living raise. Are you sure your expectations are in line with the real world?